# Bring selected item values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table in html and what I am trying to do is that when I give the button assign with jquery it brings me the values ​​of the select and the model

```html
 <button type="button" class="assign" id="assign">assign</button>
        <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>SELECT</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Escort</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
               <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Ranger</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Tacoma</td>
              <td>Red</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Mustang</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mercury</td>
              <td>Sable</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Corolla</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
$('.assign').click(function(e) {
    var select = Here the value of select
    var model =  Here is the model value
    console.log(select );
    console.log(model );
  });
});
```

And additional put me the select disabled

Comment: Follow these tips, revise your code and try again.
1: "assign" is not an input type. Give the button an id. `id="assign"1
2. Give your select tags an individual id and name (those could be the same for each select but never repeat id or name for another select.
3. Also, WHICH select are you trying to get the values of?

Comment: Sorry `id="assign"` or `class="assign"`

Comment: `id="assign"` for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an idea how you can do it. Iterating each one of rows and get the model of your row and get the selected item, something like this:

```
$('#assign').on('click', function(e){
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).children().find("select").find(":selected").text());
        console.log($(this).children()[1].textContent);         
    })
});
```

An advice ID's must be uniques, so you should change that in each one of your selects.

Comment: That brings me all the values, I need the specific, example `selected` `A Abel`   
Bring me the model  `Ford`

Comment: Do you want that your table to be selectable? @Eduard

Comment: No, when I choose in `selected A Abelse` I take the data from that row for a variable.

Comment: I don't understand at all, do you want to assing the value of the row when the `select` change? @Eduard